# R - user defined function to replace missing values

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, missing-data

I am trying to create a user-defined function to replace missing values in each variable using specific probabilities.

I can get the probabilities to print, but the second part of the code does not seem to work and all the missing values still remain.

I do not get any particular error message so puzzled why it is not working.

My data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

structure(list(id = c("395891", "373742", "316241", "282072", 
"341331", "251761", "154591", "125051", "095361", "141822", "281411", 
"31571", "165191", "03212", "08091", "26172", "135561", "164331", 
"344511", "37352"), ph201_01 = c(1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA), ph201_02 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), ph201_03 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), ph201_04 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

My code:

```
# Create user-defined function
create_mock_vars = function(var) {

  # get prevalence
  prev = round(sum(mydata[[var]], na.rm=TRUE)/nrow(mydata), 2)
  print(glue("Prevalence of {var} is {prev}."))

  mydata[[var]][is.na(mydata[[var]])] = sample(0:1, size=sum(is.na(mydata[[var]])), replace=TRUE, prob=c(prev, 1-prev))

  return(mydata)
}

# Get list of variable names I want to impute
myvarnames = names(mydata[,-1])

# Apply my function
sapply(myvarnames, create_mock_vars)

glimpse(mydata)
```

Comment: Hi Dani. Your example code does not run. Could you check your `structure` code for 'My data:' as well as the code for `create_mock_vars ` (there is at least a closing parenthesis missing.) Also could you specify all needed `library` calls?

Comment: And is there a specific reason why you use `dput(names(mydata[,2:ncol(mydata)]))` instead of just `names(mydata[,-1])`?

Comment: @dario Thanks Dario, I've copied a slightly longer version of my dataset. I can't seem to find any missing closing parenthesis... and sorry about the last bit - bad coding on my part.

Comment: Just try to run the code for `create_mock_vars ` you provided.. there is something missing

Comment: Sorry - found it and closed!

Comment: *found it and closed* - does that mean you closed the parentheses or your question is answered? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the user-defined function as :

```
create_mock_vars = function(x) {
   prev <- sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)/length(x)
   x[is.na(x)] <- sample(0:1, size = sum(is.na(x)), replace=TRUE, 
                         prob= c(prev, 1-prev))
   return(x)
}
```

and use `lapply` to apply it to each `myvarnames` columns

```
mydata[myvarnames] <- lapply(mydata[myvarnames], create_mock_vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean so here are two Base R solutions:

```
df1 <- data.frame(lapply(df,
                         function(x) {
                           if (is.numeric(x) & sum(is.na(x)) == length(x)) {
                             NA_integer_
                           } else if (is.numeric(x)) {
                             ifelse(is.na(x), sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) / length(x), x)
                           } else{
                             ifelse(is.na(x), na.omit(x)[cumsum(!is.na(x))], x)
                           }
                         }))

df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df,
                        function(x) {
                          if (is.numeric(x)) {
                            ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) == length(x), 1, 
                                   ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) != length(x),
                                          sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) / length(x), x))
                          } else{
                            ifelse(is.na(x), na.omit(x)[cumsum(!is.na(x))], x)
                          }
                        }))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    id = c("395891", "373742", "316241", "282072",
           "341331", "251761"),
    ph201_01 = c(1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L),
    ph201_02 = c(
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_
    ),
    ph201_03 = c(
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_
    ),
    ph201_04 = c(
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_,
      NA_integer_
    )
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I'm looking for, which is that the final output will all have 0/1 (except for the first column - id). The probability is used to randomly assign each missing observation a 1/0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this but without creating a user-defined function. Still, it would be great if someone could help me figure out what I did wrong for future reference?

```
myvarnames = names(mydata[,-1])

for (i in myvarnames) {
  prev = round(sum(mydata[[i]], na.rm=TRUE)/nrow(mydata), 2) # prevalence of deficit
  mydata[[i]][is.na(mydata[[i]])] = sample(0:1, size=sum(is.na(mydata[[i]])), replace=TRUE, prob=c(prev, 1-prev))
}

glimpse(mydata)
```

Comment: Besides the missing parenthesis, the main reason your custom function wouldn't work is because you mutated only the local (i.e. in the environment of the *function* variable `mydata` existing). The global version of `mydata`, the one you wanted to mutate the values in, was never changed by the function. This is because R uses *lexical scoping*, which roughly spoken, means that each code block (i.e. function) has its own `lexicon` of variable definitions. While we can call and use objects from the parent environment in R, but we don't mutate them (except we, which we never should, use ``<<-`).

Comment: Your new solutions structuring seems to me to be much better and easier to work with!

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the explanation. That was very helpful and I can see that the solution reflects this.